# Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem.To is empty

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin

I am encountering a strange issue in my outlook addin application. It is being run on Outlook 2010.
I enter an email address e.g: abc@foo.com into the "TO..." box in the email. I have the following code to get the recipients:

```
var dynamicMailItem = (dynamic) mailItem;
var recipients = (string)dynamicMailItem.To;
```

However, recipients returns an empty string! But when I evaluate dynamicMailItem.To in the immediate window, all of a sudden, the value is returned. How can I force consistent behavior?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You're improperly casting `dynamicMailItem.To`, which is why the variable `recipients` contains nothing after the fact.

The code you posted isn't valid - there's one extra close bracket. It must not be an exact copy paste from your add-in, or you would see a compile error. Can you post exactly the code you have that assigns the value of `var recipients`?

Comment: Cleaned up the code a little. I removed the right most paren from dynamicMailItem.To;

Comment: @laconicdev Really - that's your original code? Are you sure in your code you aren't, say, trying to Split `(string)dynamicMailItem.To` into a list of strings? Because if you are, that's where your problem will lie. Simply casting it to `string` (which it is) would not cause this problem: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook._mailitem.to.aspx